# When do I get the gold/full gold skins in Fortnite?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I play Fortnite, and am currently at Tier 159. I have the Full Gold version of Midas and Partly Gold Brutus. Can someone tell me when I will get the Partly Gold and Fully Gold versions of the other Battle Pass skins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, each of the gold versions of the skins unlock at specific levels the lowest being Midas's which is at level 100 and the highest being Agent Peele's which is at a whopping level 300. Once their req. level is reached you need to keep levelling up by playing with that specific character to make them fully gold. The transformation happens gradually.

The specifics (1st is the level mentioned you req. for the transformation to start):

Midas: 100 Levels (Full Gold: Level 140)

Brutus: 140 Levels (Full Gold: Level 180)

Meowscles: 180 Levels (Full Gold: Level 220)

TNTina: 220 Levels (Full Gold: Level 260)

Skye: 260 Levels (Full Gold: Level 300)

Agent Peely: 300 Levels (Full Gold: Level 340)

Hope this answered your question EagleGaming